# Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows 8 RTM causes Access Denied Error

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

**Note these things:**

- I have Windows 8 RTM.
- I have Visual Studio 2012 RTM.
- I have Microsoft Advertising SDK RTM.

*All I do is: Add a reference to it.*

**The Error:**

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOutSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOut(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action action, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TResult,TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Func`2 func, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.CreateDesignerImpl(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, RemoteCancellationToken remoteCancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass12.<Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__11(RemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.CallWithCancellation[TResult](CancellationToken cancelToken, Func`2 func)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)

System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalIn(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn(IRemoteObject targetObject, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn[TResult](IRemoteObject targetObject, Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass8.<CreateDesignerImpl>b__6(IRemoteDesignerService d)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass4`2.<MarshalOut>b__3()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at System.Reflection.Adds.NativeMethods.SafeOpenFile(String fileName)
   at System.Reflection.Adds.FileMapping..ctor(String fileName)
   at System.Reflection.Adds.MetadataDispenser.OpenFileAsFileMapping(String fileName)
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.Loader.LoadAssemblyFromFile(String file)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.WindowsRuntimeContext.LoadRuntimeAssemblyUsingReferenceType(String path)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.WindowsRuntimeContext.LoadRuntimeAssemblyFrom(String path)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.WindowsRuntimeContext.LoadFrom(String path)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.AssemblyHelper.LoadFrom(String path)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Assemblies.AssemblyService.ResolveInstalledAssembly(String path)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Assemblies.AssemblyService.ResolveAssembly(String assemblyPath, String assemblyFullName, String projectPath, IHostShadowCopyTask hostShadowCopyTask)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Assemblies.ProjectAssemblyResolver.GetAssemblyInformation(String path, String assemblyFullName)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Assemblies.ProjectAssemblyResolver.GetAssemblyInformation(IHostReferenceItem reference)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Assemblies.ProjectAssemblyResolver.UpdateAssemblyReferences(IEnumerable`1 referencesToUpdate)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Assemblies.ProjectAssemblyResolver..ctor(IHostProject project, DesignerContext designerContext)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Assemblies.ProjectAssemblyService.<.ctor>b__0(IHostProject project)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Collections.SuspendableKeyedCollection`2.CreateItems(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Collections.SuspendableKeyedCollection`2.GetItem(TKey key)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Assemblies.ProjectAssemblyService.GetProjectAssemblyResolver(IHostProject project)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Project.ProjectContextBase.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Project.XamlProjectContext.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetProjectContext(IHostProject project, IPlatform platform, Boolean create)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetSourceItemContext(IHostSourceItem sourceItem)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.DesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass10.<>c__DisplayClass12.<Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__f(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.CallWithCancellation[TResult](IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken, Func`2 func)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__e()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass16`1.<MarshalIn>b__15()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may be related to a known issue slated for a fix in a future update. In the meantime can you try the following and see if it resolves the issue:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio
2. Make sure there are no instances of `xDescProc.exe` or `MSBuild.exe` running on the machine
3. From an admin command prompt run:

> "C:\Windows\system32\icacls.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs" /grant
>   "*S-1-15-2-1":(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE) /grant "*S-1-15-2-1":(RX)

This assumes that Microsoft Advertising SDK is installed at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs

Then restart Visual Studio and open the XAML Designer.

Comment: Yeah it just tells me incorrect volume, I have it installed in the default directory

Comment: When is the Advertising SDK coming out then? It's said mid-sept...it's mid-sept

Comment: sorry Rob, there was a quotation mark missing in the command and I've edited it.  I don't see the crash, but the command now works for me. As for the SDK ETA, I don't know any more than what's posted on the site.

Comment: So what does this command do? It slowly made my computer become a crawl, and then it just stopped responding...

Comment: gory detail at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525(v=WS.10).aspx but basically is changes the access control for the given SID - it shouldn't have a performance impact.  Will try to get some addition insight for you and report back.

Comment: Hmm seems to work after a restart.  My computer froze up with that damn built in System Microsoft Anti Virus.  It scans too much

Comment: This is still an issue months later. Windows 8 Pro, Visual Studio 2012 Pro.

Comment: I'm getting it, but with WAMS instead of the Advertising SDK: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs\MobileServicesManagedClient\0.2.0.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral' is denied.

Comment: That worked for me, except I had to capitalize the "s" in "system32" - when I had the lower-case "s", "I got "The system cannot find the path specified. 0 files processed."