# Visual Studio Designer crashing Windows 8 System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

I am attempting to create Windows 8 application in Visual Studio using Component Arts charting controls. Everytime I open the designer in VS, I get the following error:

System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs\ComponentArt.WinRT.DV.Charting\2012.1.1871\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral' is denied

Not sure what security settings I'm supposed to give to this path to make VS happy!

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is a known issue with Microsoft. You can check the solution for this issue in the below SO thread.

[Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows 8 RTM causes Access Denied Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443845/microsoft-advertising-sdk-for-windows-8-rtm-causes-access-denied-error)